# In Android, is there any reason to set up a content provider for a local database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android application with a custom content provider set up to load data asychonously. The database is a local file so I'm not sure if I needed to set up a content provider at all. Sometimes I just need to do something like get a name back from a short list by id. Is it ok to mix the content provider pattern with simple direct database calls, i.e open, query, close type of code blocks?

Comment: You will likely generate an exception for attempting to perform a blocking operation on the UI thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why to use web services instead of direct access to a relational database for an android app?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170463/why-to-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-access-to-a-relational-database-for-an)

Comment: @MichaelT: I donot think that this is a duplicate because, the proposed dupliate question is about a remote database / remote webservice. This question is about local  database/loal contentprovider.

Comment: @k3b the question was edited after that was suggested. If you look at revision 1, it was unclear or a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

> You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to
>   share your data with other applications. However, you do need your own
>   provider to provide custom search suggestions in your own application.
>   You also need your own provider if you want to copy and paste complex
>   data or files from your application to other applications.